# Scraping data from website with selenium and pandas

Tags: pandas

Scraping a website and the table looks like this and i think it has two tables because the rank and names are a separate table, so im not sure how to get all that and put it all together as 1 csv
this is the website i want to scrape, its a partial table without membership
https://fantasydata.com/nba/dfs-projections/fanduel?date=02-03-2022&dfsoperator=2&dfsslateid=18504

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQsoM.png)

Im useing

```
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"table"))) 

dfs = pd.read_html(driver.page_source, header=None)
driver.implicitly_wait(120)
dvp_projections = {}
for idx, table in enumerate(dfs):
    temp_df = table.iloc[1:]
    dvp_projections[idx] = temp_df
    
temp_df.to_csv('/home/joe/NBA/Sportsdata_dvp.csv' ,index=False)
```

but im only getting this and also im missing the header
[List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mN2F.png)

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is join/merge/concat the tables. But you'll want them to concat the columns, not the rows (which is what pd.concat() does by default.)

So try:

```
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```